# Unix For loop in Command Line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to do run below command in my UNIX console:

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done
```

However, the result I am getting is below

```
{1..5}
```

Could someone suggest what's wrong with this?

Comment: Make sure you are using bash not `dash` or `sh`

Comment: When I run `for i in seq 1 5; do echo $i; done` it worked fine for me(in BASH), how about if you use `for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo $i; done`?

Comment: What is the output of echo $SHELL? Brace expansion is a shell dependent feature and it is present in `ksh`, `bash`, and `zsh` (from the top of my head) but not on `csh`, nor on `tcsh`, for example. The most probable cause of that not being expanded is lack of support on your default shell.